# Editable/fillable PDF Form - Send email with attached full PDF not just FDF

Tags: pdftex, forms

I've created a editable/fillable PDF (using the hyperref package) which I would like to send by email. I've added a button to the PDF that calls the action event from the Form. It basically looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}[action={mailto:receiver@invalid?subject=Subject&body=bodytext}, method=post]
   \TextField[name=name]{Name:}\\[1mm]
   \Submit[width=4.00cm, height=1.00cm, borderstyle=S]{\Large{Send email}}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

This works but only sends the filled out values as FDF file attached to an email.

I need the full PDF with the entered content.

Is it possible to attach the full PDF instead of just the FDF file containing the values (maybe with the help of another package)?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done by the parameter "export" of the Submit-Element:

```
\Submit[export=PDF]{Button-text}
```

"Known formats are 'FDF', 'HTML', 'XFDF', and 'PDF'"
(quoted from file "hyperref.sty", around line 5670, MiKTex 2.9)

Comment: Thank you for the working solution. Sorry, it took me that long to follow up on this.